# Запрос на выборку с исключением

Tags: mysql

Всем Ку! Пытаюсь сформировать запрос на выборку по атрибутам и их статусам (`value`):

```
entity_id | attribute_id | value
--------------------------------
141978    | 590          | 1
141978    | 591          | 1
188141    | 590          | 0
188141    | 591          | 1

SELECT entity_id, attribute_id, value FROM table
WHERE attribute_id IN (590, 591)
AND value = 1
GROUP BY entity_id, value;
```

Получаю

```
 entity_id | attribute_id | value
---------------------------------
141978     | 590          | 1
188141     | 591          | 1
```

Но мне необходимо получить только те сущности, у которых нет атрибутов со статусом (`value`) `0`, как-то так:

```
entity_id 
---------
141978
```

Но заглох) Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: *Ответа от вас не было* Не могу не ответить, хотя Ваш собственный ответ и удалён. Просто не успел (на работе я, отвлекают, знаете ли) написать ещё один пост о том, что опубликованный ответ НЕ соответствует задаче в том виде, в каком она сформулирована. И именно по этой причине я не дал Вам ответ. Да, Вы товарищ опытный, разберётесь - основа решения такого рода задач лежит в области `HAVING SUM(value = 1) > 0 AND SUM(value = 0) > 0` или `HAVING SUM(value != 0) < COUNT(value)`, с вариациями в зависимости от конкретной задачи.

Comment: @Akina Благодарю за замечания, я с ними полностью согласен.

Comment: Возникают вопросы. 1) В первых двух исходных записях 2 последние цифры переставлены - опечатка? 2) Почему выведена запись с `attribute_id=590` и проигнорирована с `attribute_id=591`? 3) Зачем вообще выводить `attribute_id` и `value`? А если нужно только `entity_id`, то `SELECT entity_id FROM table WHERE attribute_id IN (590, 591) GROUP BY entity_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attribute_id) = 2 AND SUM(value = 0) = 0`. Ну или `AND MIN(value) = 1`, или ещё как.

Comment: Да, падон, опечатка, спешка, исправил

Answer (score 0):

Так?

```
SELECT entity_id, attribute_id, value FROM table
WHERE attribute_id IN (590, 591) AND value != 0
```

Comment: К сожалению, нет.  У  сущности 141978 есть атрибуты со статусами 1 и 0. И он попадает в выборку по статусу 1